# Keep images in memory between Cycles renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance

I have an application which requires me to render hundreds of thousands of tiny images in Cycles.

The scene uses a HDR Light Probe, which is ~100mb uncompressed in VRAM.
I've noticed that the majority of time for each render, up to 500ms, is used up loading this, and another texture.

Here's a section of the render output, notice the time taken loading the images:

```
Fra:60 Mem:7.22M (0.00M, Peak 122.50M) | Time:00:00.16 | Mem:0.07M, Peak:0.07M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Images
Fra:60 Mem:7.22M (0.00M, Peak 122.50M) | Time:00:00.16 | Mem:0.07M, Peak:0.07M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Images | Loading lightbox3.hdr
Fra:60 Mem:7.22M (0.00M, Peak 122.50M) | Time:00:00.16 | Mem:0.07M, Peak:0.07M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Images | Loading floor_cardboard.png
Fra:60 Mem:122.82M (0.00M, Peak 122.82M) | Time:00:00.60 | Mem:115.67M, Peak:115.67M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Camera Volume
Fra:60 Mem:122.82M (0.00M, Peak 122.82M) | Time:00:00.60 | Mem:115.67M, Peak:115.67M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Hair Systems
Fra:60 Mem:122.82M (0.00M, Peak 122.82M) | Time:00:00.60 | Mem:115.67M, Peak:115.67M | Scene, RenderLayer | Updating Hair settings | Copying Hair settings to device
```

This amount of time may not seem like much, but it's more than doubling my rendering time over thousands of renders.

Is there any way to keep the loaded images in memory across renders, or change my workflow in some way so this works?

I'm using the Cycles setting 'Persistent Images' but I guess that only applies across animation frames, not individual image renders.